# Faster way to truncate range of tables by query?

Tags: php, sql, truncate

I am trying to truncate the range of tables from 1 to 100.

```
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
  $qryTruncate = "TRUNCATE `tbl_$i`";
   $resultTruncate = mysqli_query($conn, $qryTruncate);
}
```

it takes too long to do truncate all tables.

Do you have any suggestion to make it faster way?

Comment: It's unusual to have tables named like this, perhaps redesigning the database would achieve want you need.

Comment: Why would you have so many tables named in such a strange way. This is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is drop the table and recreate it like this.

Rename table -> create new table like it -> drop old table

```
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
  mysqli_query($conn, "RENAME TABLE `tbl_$i` `temp_tbl_$i`");
  mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE `tbl_$i` LIKE `temp_tbl_$i`");
  mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE `temp_tbl_$i`");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code take double longer to be finish. mine code take 2 min 25 sec and your code 4 min 40 sec .